# Angularjs start date and end date validations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, date

I am completely New to Angularjs and trying to validate 2 scenarios. I have 2 text boxes one with start date and the other with end date. I am checking

1. Show validation error on UI if start date is not greater than or equal to today. It should be today or any day after today.
2. Show validation error on UI if start date is greater than end date. End date should be greater than start date.

I tried the below code which did not work. Any suggestions please.

Html Code

```
<label for="endDate" class="control-label">Start Date:</label>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
           id="startDate" ng-model="startDate" />
</div>

<label for="text" class="control-label">End Date:</label>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
           id="endDate" ng-model="endDate" 
            ng-change='checkErr(startDate,endDate)' />

</div>

<span>{{errMessage}}</span>
```

js code

```
$scope.checkErr = function(startDate,endDate){
    $scope.errMessage = '';
    $scope.curDate = new Date();

    if(startDate < endDate){
      $scope.errMessage = 'End Date should be greate than start date';
      return false;
    }
    if(startDate < curDate){
       $scope.errMessage = 'Start date should not be before today.';
       return false;
    }

  };
```

- I have input type as text for both date controls.I am using bootstrap date picker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have the logic reversed on the first bit and you have to construct a new date from startDate to compare to today's date. Also you set curDate to the scope, `$scope.curDate = new Date()` but then you were referencing it as `curDate` without the `$scope` so it was undefined. Lastly, you need to cast `stateDate` and `endDate` to a date as well. Otherwise you're just comparing strings.

```
$scope.checkErr = function(startDate,endDate) {
    $scope.errMessage = '';
    var curDate = new Date();

    if(new Date(startDate) > new Date(endDate)){
      $scope.errMessage = 'End Date should be greater than start date';
      return false;
    }
    if(new Date(startDate) < curDate){
       $scope.errMessage = 'Start date should not be before today.';
       return false;
    }
};
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/peceLm14/

Comment: Code is little different from fiddle you posted. But this helped a lot. Please sync code you posted and fiddle so that it will be useful for everyone.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about casting the dates in the first if block.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're referencing `curDate` which is undefined. Change the conditional to `if (startDate < $scope.curDate)`. See fiddle for working example http://jsfiddle.net/4ec3atzk/1/

```
$scope.checkErr = function(startDate,endDate){
  $scope.errMessage = '';
  $scope.curDate = new Date();

  if (startDate < endDate){
    $scope.errMessage = 'End Date should be greate than start date';
    return false;
  }

  if (new Date(startDate) < $scope.curDate){
    $scope.errMessage = 'Start date should not be before today.';
    return false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.datepickerObjectfromdates = {
    todayLabel: 'Today',
    closeLabel: 'Close',
    setLabel: 'Ok',
    setButtonType : 'button-calm',
    todayButtonType : 'button-calm',
    closeButtonType : 'button-calm',
    inputDate: new Date(),
    mondayFirst: true,
    templateType: 'popup',
    showTodayButton: 'true',
    modalHeaderColor: 'bar-calm',
    modalFooterColor: 'bar-calm',
    callback: function (val) {
        var getdate = GetFormattedFromDates(val);
        $scope.date.FromDates = getdate;
        localStorage.date = $scope.FromDates;

    },
    dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yyyy', //Optional
    closeOnSelect: false, //Optional
};
function GetFormattedFromDates(val) {
    if(typeof(val)==='undefined')
    {
        $scope.date.FromDates = '';
    }
    else {

        var todayTime = new Date(val);
        var month = todayTime.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = todayTime.getDate();


        if (month < 10) {
            month = '0' + month;
        }
        if (day < 10) {
            day = '0' + day;
        }


        var year = todayTime.getFullYear();
        return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    }

}


$scope.datepickerObjecttodates = {

    todayLabel: 'Today',
    closeLabel: 'Close',
    setLabel: 'Ok',
    setButtonType : 'button-calm',
    todayButtonType : 'button-calm',
    closeButtonType : 'button-calm',
    inputDate: new Date(),
    mondayFirst: true,
    templateType: 'popup',
    allowOldDates: false,

    showTodayButton: 'true',
    modalHeaderColor: 'bar-calm',
    modalFooterColor: 'bar-calm',

    callback: function (val) {
        var getdate = GetFormattedToDates(val);
        $scope.date.ToDates = getdate;
        //$scope.date.ToDates = getdate.clear();


    },

    dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy', //Optional
    closeOnSelect: false, //Optional

};
function GetFormattedToDates(val) {
    if (typeof(val) === 'undefined') {
        $scope.ToDates = '';
    }
    else {
        var todayTime = new Date(val);

        var month = todayTime.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = todayTime.getDate();


        if (day < 10) {
            day = '0' + day;
        }
        if (month < 10) {
            month = '0' + month;
        }
        var year = todayTime.getFullYear();
        return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    }

}
```