# Start date and end date validations angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350345/angularjs-start-date-and-end-date-validations)

I have a form which has start date and end date with date pickers. The user can add more than one date in the form. In this case the first from date and to date select boxes will be cloned and appended to the form.

I need to check the validity of the dates in each from date and to date pair. That is if to date is smaller than from date error message should be displayed near the to date. I have added the code below. Thanks.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <span ng-repeat="data in userdata">
    <ng-form name="repeatForm">
        <input type="text" name="expFromDate" ng-model="form.fromDate"/>
        <input type="text" name="expToDate" ng-model="form.toDate"/>
        <span class="error input-icon fui-alert input-icon-check" ng-show="repeatForm.expToDate.$error.expFromDate"></span>
    </ng-form>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add relevant code and/or create a JsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Rather than cloning the date boxes with jQuery or so, you should use an ng-repeat like:

```
<input ng-repeat="fromDate in ctrl.fromDates" type="text" name="expFromDate" ng-model="fromDate"/>
<input ng-repeat="toDate in ctrl.toDates" type="text" name="expFromDate" ng-model="toDate"/>
```

Then you can have a method on your controller to do the validation:

```
<span class="error input-icon fui-alert input-icon-check" ng-show="!ctrl.datesValid()"></span>

public datesValid(): boolean {
    return _.all(this.fromDates, date => ...)
        && _.all(this.toDates, date => ...);
};
```