# From date , To date validation in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, frontend

This is my code

```
<tr ng-show="option == 'Yearly' || option == 'Date'">
  <td>
    <label>From:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="date" ng-model="fromdate" id="fromdate" date-picker />
  </td>
  <td>
    <label>To:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="date" ng-model="todate" date-picker />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have a jquery date picker for fromdate and todate, I need to disable all the dates in the end date which is lesser than the from date.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs start date and end date validations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350345/angularjs-start-date-and-end-date-validations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker
previously and [minDate](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#maxdate) and [maxDate](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate) options can probably be helpful for your use case, if you want to look at another plugin.

Sample usage to set `maxDate`, `minDate`:

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  maxDate: new Date("6/8/2016"),
  minDate: new Date("6/2/2016")
});
```

Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ye9pzq2QVWkdargwt3DO)

Note: This plugin has dependency on `bootstrap`, `jquery`, and `momentjs`

Edit:

There is also a angular wrapper directive over this: https://github.com/diosney/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to set a specific min date like todays date you can put that in as a setting.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D

If you have an easy way of setting your min date to be todays day you can just use a variable as such min="{{minDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"). Note that min will also add native HTML5 constraint validation.

In theory this doesn't require a controller but just a app setup config for $scope.minDate, all that is going to do is note that your date is not correct next to the field with whatever validation you have set, field and form validation is a whole different animal then what you are asking but I would read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms on it.

In the long run I wouldn't use jquery date picker and use a native directive like https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ Date picker or Angular Material https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker

Comment: I have a directive and I need to pass values to it from the front end i.e I need to pass fromdate and todate to the directive.. Can you help me out

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the directive?  Not sure why you can't just put a scope variable or do some logic in the link function.